How to use nginx with springboot api to verify resource access?
I have two links like this, "[http://localhost:80/img/private-1.jpg -> http://localhost:9631/img/private-1.jpg]" and "[http://localhost:80/img/public/public-1.jpg -> http://localhost:9631/img/public/public-1.jpg]";
Because there was no permission control before, all users can access it.
Now I want to cooperate with springboot api to make url starting with "/img/public" accessible to any user, and url starting with "/img/" require users to log in or have a link with a valid token in the link to access it.
So how do I configure nginx and how to write api.
This is what is done for "/img/public/" and it works fine：
    # Handle /img/public/* direct access
    location /img/public/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9631;  # Forward requests to port 9631
        
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }


Why you do Not use spring security?

Because this resource file link comes from the OBS server, Spring Security seems to be unable to manage these resources. If it is possible, do you have a link to the relevant documentation?

I have solved the problem, here are the relevant configurations.
nginx.conf
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    # Handle /img/public/* direct access
    location /img/public/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9631; # Forward the request to port 9631

        # Pass the original request header in the header
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    # Handle /img/* requires permission verification
    location /img/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9631;
        auth_request /img-auth-verify;
        set $token $arg_token;
    }

    # Handle verification requests, internal access
    location = /img-auth-verify {
        internal; # Restrict direct access
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9631/img-auth/verify/; # Make sure there is a trailing slash
        proxy_pass_request_body off; # Do not forward the request body
        proxy_set_header Content-Length ""; # Clear Content-Length
        proxy_set_header X-Orginal-URI $request_uri; # Pass the original request URI
        proxy_set_header AccessToken "$token";
    }
}

java code
@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/img-auth/")
public class ImgAuthController {

    private static final Random random = new Random();

    @GetMapping("/verify/")
    public ResponseEntity<String> verifyImgAuthPermissions(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String originalUri = request.getHeader("X-Orginal-URI");
        log.debug("originalUri: {}", originalUri);
        String accessToken = request.getHeader("accessToken");
        boolean logged = random.nextBoolean();
        log.debug("accessToken: {}, logged: {}", accessToken, logged);
        if (logged) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).build();
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).build();
        }
    }
}

springboot application.yaml
spring:
  application:
    name: rest-api
  web:
    resources:
      static-locations: file:D:\static\
      add-mappings: true
  mvc:
    static-path-pattern: /img/**
server:
  port: 9631

logging:
  level:
    com.rest.restapi: debug

js html-test-page body
<div style="width: 100%">
<label>http://localhost:9631/img/public/public-1.jpg
    <button style="margin-left: 10px" onclick="changeUrl(this)">change</button>
    <button style="margin-left: 10px" onclick="changeUrl(this, true)">change token</button>
</label><br/>
<label>http://localhost:9631/img/public/public-2.jpg
    <button style="margin-left: 10px" onclick="changeUrl(this)">change</button>
    <button style="margin-left: 10px" onclick="changeUrl(this, true)">change token</button>
</label><br/>
</div>

<div style="width: 100%; margin-top: 10px; padding-top: 10px; border-top: solid 1px">
    <label>http://localhost:80/img/private-1.jpg
        <button style="margin-left: 10px" onclick="changeUrl(this)">change</button>
        <button style="margin-left: 10px" onclick="changeUrl(this, true)">change token</button>
    </label><br/>
    <label>http://localhost:80/img/private-2.jpg
        <button style="margin-left: 10px" onclick="changeUrl(this)">change</button>
        <button style="margin-left: 10px" onclick="changeUrl(this, true)">change token</button>
    </label><br/>
</div>
<div id="container" style="height: 500px; width: 100%; margin-top: 30px">
    <img id="img" src="http://localhost:9631/img/public/public-1.jpg"
         style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%; object-fit: contain;">
</div>

js html-test-page script
<script>
    const container = document.getElementById('container')

    function changeUrl(button, isChangeToken) {
        container.replaceChildren();
        const label = button.parentElement;
        const url = label.textContent.trim().split(' ')[0];
        let img = document.createElement('img');
        if (isChangeToken) {
            const token = randomUUID(5);
            const name = randomUUID(5);
            const key = randomUUID(5);
            img.src = `${url}?token=${token}&key=${key}&name=${name}`;
        } else{
            img.src = url;
        }

        img.style.maxWidth = '100%';
        img.style.maxHeight = '100%';
        img.style.objectFit = 'contain';
        container.append(img);
    }

    function randomUUID(length = 32) {
        if (length < 5 || length > 32 || length === null) {
            length = 32;
        }
        const chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
        let uuid = '';
        
        let firstChar;
        do {
            firstChar = chars.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length));
        } while (firstChar === '0');
        uuid += firstChar;
        
        for (let i = 1; i < length; i++) {
            uuid += chars.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length));
        }
        return uuid;
    }
</script>

